# obtain requirements from HP ALM executing a query of a concrete target version

Tags: c#, api, rest, alm, requirements

I need to obtain all the requirements in a corporate HPE ALM of a concrete target version (field user-template-18). To obtain these requirements, I'm using the next url in my code within the C# project that I'm developing:
http://<hp_alm>/qcbin/rest/domains/<name_domain>/projects/<name_project>/requirements/?fields=id,name,description,user-03,user-template-18

With the previous url, I obtain via url navigator all these fields of a concrete id available in corporate HPE ALM. My final goal is to achieve how to implement/execute the next sql in my code project.

If I execute directly the next sql in HP ALM console, returns correctly the desired requirements of a concrete target version:
select id,name,description,user-03,user-template-18
from req
where type_id = '108'
and user-template-18 = '<version_target>'

Could anyone specify how to implement the code to obtain all the requirements executing the previous sql of a concrete target version in a c# project?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where are you stuck in achieving your goal? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've developed the next method to obtain all requirements for a concrete target version of HP ALM (<target_version>) and I've an error in the line XmlSerializer.

Could you confirm which error exists in attached code?

public Entity LoginAlm (string url, string username, string password, string domain, string project, string targetVersion)
{

```
        var client = new RestClient(url + "/qcbin/");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        var Domain = domain;
        var Project = project;

        var getItems1 = new RestRequest("authentication-point/authenticate");
        IRestResponse response1 = client.Execute(getItems1);

        var getItems2 = new RestRequest("rest/site-session", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response2 = client.Execute(getItems2);

        string sql = "select id,name,description,user-03,user-31,user-template-03,father-name " +
            "from req where type_id = '108' and user-template-18 = '<target_version>'";

        var getReqs = new RestRequest("rest/domains/" + Domain + "/projects/" + Project + "/requirements?query=[{" + sql + '}' + ']');

        getReqs.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        getReqs.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");

        getReqs.AddParameter("domain", Domain, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        getReqs.AddParameter("project", Project, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(getReqs);

        var reader = new StringReader(response.Content);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Entity));
        var instance = (Entity)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return instance;//JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        
    }
```